Adding annotations on images in minipage
I am trying to add a visual annotation (a rectangle) on an eps file directly using LaTex. I have attached the desired outcome below :

For that, this is my code :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % Définition de la taille de la première colonne
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel={$x$},
    ylabel={$z$},
    domain=-5:5,
    samples=200,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize, at={(1.25,0.75)}, anchor=north}, % Déplacer et redimensionner la légende
    xmin=-1.2,
    xmax=1.2,
    ymin=-0.2,
    ymax=1.2,
    xtick=\empty, % Ne pas afficher les graduations sur l'axe des x
    ytick=\empty  % Ne pas afficher les graduations sur l'axe des y
]
% Courbe f(x)
\addplot[color=blue,ultra thick,domain=-0.75:0.75] {0.65 - sqrt(0.65^2-x^2)};
% Courbe x^2
\addplot[color=red,ultra thick,domain=-1:1] {x^2};
\draw[dashed,orange!90, stealth-stealth, ultra thick] (0,0) -- node[right,scale=0.85] {$ \frac{1}{\kappa}$} (0,0.6);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage} % Fin de la première colonne
\hfill % Espace horizontal entre les deux colonnes
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % Définition de la taille de la deuxième colonne
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test.eps} 
\end{minipage} % Fin de la deuxième colonne
\caption{Légende commune pour les deux figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

Initially, I wanted to have the same output as this post Adding inset in Latex but I didn't manage to have a very understandable figure so I only expect to add a rectangle but I am not able to apply the proposition of the related post since I am using minipage and tend to avoid putting images as nodes...
Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Even with a minipage you can add a tikzpicture and put the \includegraphics command in a node, with the desired rectangle
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
  \draw[thick] (-5mm, -10mm) rectangle (5mm,-15mm);
\end{tikzpicture}

Full example, with some minor corrections:

I swapped the two figures, like in the desired outcome.
I added width=\linewidth, scale only axis to limit the size of the axis picture.
I removed the \centering inside the two minipage, since the content takes the whole line width.
I added axis cs: in the coordinates of the orange arrow, to make it use the axis coordinate system.
I limited the domain of the blue curve to -0.65;0.65 where it is defined.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % Définition de la taille de la première colonne
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
      \draw[thick] (-5mm, -10mm) rectangle (5mm,-15mm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage} % Fin de la première colonne
  \hfill % Espace horizontal entre les deux colonnes
  \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth} % Définition de la taille de la deuxième colonne
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
          width=\linewidth,
          scale only axis,
          axis lines=center,
          xlabel={$x$},
          ylabel={$z$},
          domain=-5:5,
          samples=200,
          legend style={font=\footnotesize, at={(1.25,0.75)}, anchor=north}, % Déplacer et redimensionner la légende
          xmin=-1.2,
          xmax=1.2,
          ymin=-0.2,
          ymax=1.2,
          xtick=\empty, % Ne pas afficher les graduations sur l'axe des x
          ytick=\empty  % Ne pas afficher les graduations sur l'axe des y
        ]
        % Courbe f(x)
        \addplot[color=blue,ultra thick,domain=-0.65:0.65] {0.65 - sqrt(0.65^2-x^2)};
        % Courbe x^2
        \addplot[color=red,ultra thick,domain=-1:1] {x^2};
        \draw[dashed,orange!90, stealth-stealth, ultra thick]
        (axis cs:0,0) -- (axis cs:0,0.6)
        node[midway, right, scale=0.85] {$ \frac{1}{\kappa}$} ;
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{minipage} % Fin de la deuxième colonne
  \caption{Légende commune pour les deux figures}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



thank you @jlab : I was using node with minipage in the wrong way. However, I am not sure to get why you removed \centering ? Thank you again.

@Waxler If the image is the width of the minipage, whether its alignment is left, right or center produces the same output. You can keep \centering if you want, so if you later change the size of a graph, it will stay centered.
